# Loop through array and populate table and prevent new rows, values need to be in one row?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have a array of column headers which are the table column headers. Based on these column values I want to loop through an multiple associative array and display the text where period_id equals the column header id.

I have the following function and the problem is every found value comes on a new `<tr>`:

```
     P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | P7 | P8 | P9 | P10 | P11

   |    |    | msg 1|    | msg2   |    |    |  msg3  |   |
```

and not

```
  |    |    | msg 1 |    |    |    |    |    |   |  
  |    |    |       |    | msg2   |    |    |    |    | | 
  |    |    |       |    |    |    |    |    |  msg3  | |
```

Hera are Both arrays and code which outputs each on a sperate row. I guess i am using a foreach too many. (array_map?? or list?)

```
  /***
 * Populate Table
 */

$colHeads = [
   [
            'period_id'=> 14,
            'period' => 'p1',
       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 1,
            'period' => 'p2',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 2,
            'period' => 'p2',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 4,
            'period' => 'p3',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 5,
            'period' => 'p5',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 6,
            'period' => 'p6',
       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 7,
            'period' => 'p7',
       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 8,
            'period' => 'p8',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 9,
            'period' => 'p9',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 10,
            'period' => 'p10',

       ],
   [
            'period_id'=> 11,
            'period' => 'p11',
       ],

];


$dailyFeedbacks = [
    [
        'date' => '2017-01-18',
        'period_id' => 4,
        'feedback_score' => 4,
        'feeback_notes' => 'test is pos feedack',
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2017-01-18',
        'period_id' => 6,
        'feedback_score' => 2,
        'feeback_notes' => 'test is asdf feedack',
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2017-01-18',
        'period_id' => 10,
        'feedback_score' => 2,
        'feeback_notes' => 'test is asdf feedack',
    ], 
    // Neg feedback on seperat row???
 [
        'date' => '2017-01-18',
        'period_id' => 8,
        'feedback_score' => -3,// Neg feedback
        'feeback_notes' => 'test is neg feedack',
    ], 
];


    $tableRow ='<table>';
    $tableRow .= '<tr><td>Feedback</td>';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($colHeads as $headCol) {
     foreach($dailyFeedbacks as $dailyFeedback) {
        if ($i == 11) {
                    $i = 0;
                }
             $periodHead = $headCol['period_id'];
            if ($dailyFeedback['period_id']==$periodHead ) {
                $tableRow .= '<td>'.$dailyFeedback['feeback_notes'].'</td>';
            }  else {
                $tableRow .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
            }
            $i++;
                if($i == 11){
                    $tableRow .= '</tr>';
                }
        }   
    }
    $tableRow .= '</table>';
    echo $tableRow;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to proceed as follows:

- Key the colHeads information by period ID, so that you don't have to look for it repeatedly
- Store the notes in arrays: one array per column. Keep track of how long the longest of those arrays becomes -- as this will be the number of rows in your table
- Generate the HTML for the header row based on colHeads
- Generate the HTML for the data rows based on the arrays created above

Here is the code:

```
// Key the column headers by period_id
$colMap = [];
foreach ($colHeads as $colNum => $colHead) {
    $colMap[$colHead["period_id"]] = $colNum;
}

// Store notes in array per column
$columnNotes = [];
$rowCount = 0;
foreach ($dailyFeedbacks as $feedback) {
    $colNum = $colMap[$feedback["period_id"]];
    $columnNotes[$colNum][] = $feedback["feeback_notes"];
    $rowCount = max($rowCount, count($columnNotes[$colNum]));
}

// Generate HTML for header row
$table = "";
foreach ($colHeads as $colHead) {
    $table .= "<th>" . htmlspecialchars($colHead["period"]) . "</th>";
}
// Generate HTML for data rows
$table = "<tr>$table</tr>\n"; 
foreach (range(0, $rowCount-1) as $rowNum) {
    $tableRow = "";
    foreach ($colHeads as $colNum => $colHead) {
        $tableRow .= "<td>" . (isset($columnNotes[$colNum][$rowNum]) 
            ? htmlspecialchars($columnNotes[$colNum][$rowNum])
            : "&nbsp;") . "</td>";
    }
    $table .= "<tr>$tableRow</tr>\n"; 
}
$table = "<table>\n$table</table>\n";

echo $table;
```

Comment: Tx @trincot for your answer and effort to explain it all. Only thing I don't exactly understand and it's the cause of my "bad" question is your "Keep track of how long the longest of those arrays becomes -- as this will be the number of rows in your table" . In my original project the $dailyFeedbacks array is a list of feedbacks/notes per date. So should I first loop through dailyFeedbacks array to make seperate input arrays for Columnnotes??? I thought of creating a function which gets the date as parameter and spits out the "Generate HTML for data rows"?

Comment: also i don't quit understand this part `$rowCount = max($rowCount, count($columnNotes[$colNum]));`

Comment: The `$rowCount` variable gets the length of the `$columnNodes[$colNum]`. But `$rowCount`  should never decrease in value, so if it already is higher, then it should just stay the same. This is what `max` does here. You could also write it as `if ($rowCount < count($columnNotes[$colNum])) $rowCount = count($columnNotes[$colNum]);`. The idea of `columnNotes` itself is to already assign the notes to the column they belong to. If your data is such that you can do this at an early stage, then why not?

Comment: sorry to bother you again but I have a followup question which I don't understand. I have added an array in $dailyFeedbacks which has a neg. score. I like to seperate pos/neg feedback notes each in his own row, how can this be done???

Comment: Should I created 2 seperate columNotes arrays ?